# Graph api equivalent for some FQL features

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Since FQL is deprecated and gonna be removed, are there graph api ways to get:
the profile photos album photos on a single request, like:

```
SELECT owner, src_big, images FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE type="profile" AND owner=USERID
```

traverse all the users photos on a single location/endpoint like:

```
SELECT pid, src_big, images FROM photo WHERE owner=USERID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`me/photos/uploaded?fields=id,images,source` is your best bet with pagination

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had the same problem and using field expansion this is the best I found:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=albums.limit(1).fields(name,photos.fields(name,picture,source,images))

Im assuming the first album is the profile pictures...